# APEX IG not rendering grid correctly

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am trying to add a fixed check box to an IG.  They will be able to edit other fields but not the check box.  Here is the sql and result for the IG.

```
select CAR_ID,
   CAR_NAME,
   TOP_SPEED,
   TRAC_CTRL,
   DATE_SOLD,
   CASE
     WHEN DATE_SOLD is null
    then
       APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX(1,1) 
    END "For Sale"
```

from APEX_TEST
[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help on how to get the checkbox to display correctly would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scroll further down the properties and select 'No' for Escape special characters.

[image]